flask не загружает файлы на сервер
Вот только начал изучать библиотеку flask для python'а, думаю, может консольное приложение перевести на него, но почти сразу же столкнулся с проблемой
суть в том, что надо обрабатывать входящие файлы excel, в основном по заданным алгоритмам, вот только файлы не загружаются.
Т.е. загружаются но при нажатии на submit выходит окно сохранения (типа, сохранить как...), а оно не должно выходить, ведь в конфиге я указал app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER.
def allowed_file(filename):
""" Функция проверки расширения файла """
return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
@app.route('/upload', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # проверим, передается ли в запросе файл
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('Невозможно прочитать файл')
            return redirect(request.url)
        
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('нет выбранного файла')
            return redirect(request.url)
        
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            # если все прошло успешно, то перенаправляем на функцию-представление `download_file` 
            return redirect(url_for('download_file', filename=filename))
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

в открытых источниках об этой проблеме я ничего не нашел.

Вы ж сами редиректите на ссылку для скачивания файла, вот браузер и начинает скачивать. Непонятно, чего ещё вы ожидали-то

не совсем понял Ваш ответ.
Но если я все правильно понял, данный код предназначен для загрузки файлов в папку на сервере
а return redirect(url_for('download_file', filename=filename)), в данном контексте, предназначена для загрузки файлов filename на сервер в папку UPLOAD_FOLDER.
разве нет?

Нет, url_for генерирует ссылку, redirect генерирует собственно http-ответ с редиректом, return возвращает его из функции и дальше Flask отправляет его браузеру. Браузер честно идёт по редиректу — а там в ответ ему файл присылают, вот браузеру только и остаётся что предложить сохранить его

Здравствуйте!
Да, вы правы дело в том, что я не правильно использую redirect. и еще проблема в том, что у меня имена файлов кириллицей. Это очень большая проблема
Спасибо за наводку
